# Declaração correta no CSS de listagem de menu

Tags: css

Tenho uma listagem de menu e gostaria de saber a forma mais correta de declarar no HTML+CSS.

O HTML está assim:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Empresa</li>
    <li>Produtos</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li class="logo"></li>
    <li>Onde Comprar</li>
    <li>Assistência</li>
    <li>Contato</li>
</ul>
```

Quanto ao CSS, eu gostaria de alguma dica.
Claro, eu poderia colocar uma classe em cada `li` e deixar do jeito que eu quiser, mas não sei se seria o ideal, gostaria de economizar código.

O CSS está assim:

```
ul.menu li{
    font-family: "nexa_boldregular";
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #1d1d1b;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 35px;
}
```

Por exemplo, se eu quiser estilizar alguma `li` em especifico, teria que atribuir uma classe à ela, certo? Como fiz na `logo`. O ideal no CSS, seria como?

`.logo`, `li.logo`, `ul.menu>li.logo`?

Comment: Não existe certo ou errado, vai depender do seu estilo de trabalhar ou se vai ter mais algum elemento com a classe `.logo` tem especificar que se refere ao elemento dentro do `.menu` e usar algo como: `.menu .logo`

Comment: Mas, existe uma forma mais estruturada. Para economizar trabalho.

Comment: Neste caso eu sugiro retirar as tags html do seletor, use só quando necessário... veja esse [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/7kqs2gc3/)

Comment: Editei o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/7kqs2gc3/) e agora mostra como selecionar apenas o elemento desejado, em situações que usa as mesmas classes, veja...

Comment: Valeu @Jader, ajudou muito!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Felipe,

Toda a vez que você trata apenas um elemento, você pode utilizar o `ID`. Sendo um grupo ao qual será atribuido um elemento em comum, ai você usa `Classe`

Existe a TAG `nav` a qual utilizo para geralmente estruturar da seguinte forma:

```
<nav>
  <ul
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Consecutivamente no CSS, me refiro assim:

```
nav ul {
}

nav ul li{
}
```

Ou seja, se você não possuí uma classe, você vai destrinchando os elementos e desenvolvendo a arvore.
Se você declarar um estilo para para `nav ul`, ele vai procurar uma TAG `ul` dentro do `nav`, idem ao `nav ul li` que poderia ser declarado como `nav li` por exemplo.

Sobre o `.logo`, você pode declarar a mesma singularmente porém em linhas sequencias do seu código, para organização, deixar o conteúdo relativo ao menu, totalmente agrupado. Ou seja, criar "setorizações".

Comment: Obrigado. Só uma dúvida, supondo que eu tenha mais de uma listagem de menus no site. Eu teria que criar uma classe nove para diferenciá-las, o ideal seria eu criar, assim por exemplo: `nav ul.menu1` e `nav ul.menu2`, correto?

Comment: Seguindo a sua estrutura, o correto seria você identificar a área a qual seu menu pertence. Por exemplo, um deles poderia ser `menuLateral` enquanto outro seria `menuSuperior`. Ou por exemplo, se caso um menu é principal e relativo a navegação, você poderia ter uma declaração `nav ul` e `nav li`, enquanto outro, `menuSecundario ul` e `menuSecundario li`